# Magento 2.1.7 unable to locate gallery.css file

Tags: magento-2.1, css

I need to remove a style that is listed in the below listed **gallery.css** file.

How ever I believe the path below is the location of a cached version of the file not the actual file??

I need to find the actual file and not sure were/how to find it?

```
domain.com/pub/static/version1500569382/frontend/Smartwave/porto_child/en_US/mage/gallery/gallery.css
```

any suggestions on where I can find this file? I looked in

`domain.com/app/design/frontend/Smartwave/porto_child`

however That directory does not contain a en_US folder?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to remove this file then add below code in `<theme_dir>\Magento_Catalog\layout\catalog_product_view.xml` file.

```
<head>
   <remove src="mage/gallery/gallery.css" />
</head>
```

**If you want to edit gallery style:**

If you are not locate this file in `<theme_dir>\web\mage\gallery` then copy `gallery.less` file from `<root>\lib\web\mage\gallery` and add in your theme.

**Run command:**

- php bin/magento cache:clean
- php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy

**en_US** folder is generate from themes when you run `php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy`.

Comment: When I copy over the gallery.less file from  <root>\lib\web\mage\gallery    should I change the file ext to be .css and not .less or keep the file as .less ?

Comment: You can keep `.less` ext.

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for the static file you should check in

```
domain.com/pub/static/frontend/Smartwave/porto_child/en_US/mage/gallery/gallery.css
```

Otherwise if you are looking for the original file which you want to deploy in future after finishing the changes, you should check in

```
domain.com/app/design/frontend/Smartwave/porto/mage/gallery/gallery.css
```

Since 'porto' is a parent theme for the 'porto_child', it will be there in the porto theme directory.

Comment: thank youI do not have any "mage" folder in the parent theme folder  domain.com/app/design/frontend/Smartwave/porto/
which is why I was not sure what to do. I am just trying to remove a very specific style class in the gallery.css file.

Comment: search file using the linux command 'find . -name "gallery.css"' inside <magen_root_dir>/app/design. From the result you can find where it is located.